# Setting context path in while authorizing application to access google apis using java

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to access google apis for calendar using java and spring. I succcessfully ran a sample project on the web application environment provided by google plugin in eclipse. However when I try to run the same project on Apache I run into many problems. I have this specific doubt which has hampered my progress on my project. I am not able to create a redirect url as defined in the registered application on google app engine. Using new LocalServerReceiver() in the api

return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");

creates a url shttp://localhost:/Callback 
This URL does not match with the registered one

http://localhost:8080/OAuthv2/oauth2callback which results in an error.

Using the builder api for localserverreceiver

new LocalServerReceiver().setport(8080).setHostname("localhost/Oauthv2/oauth2callback") also results in an error sayig unknown hostname.

Can anyone please help to make a redirect uri same as http://localhost:8080/OAuthv2/oauth2callback

```
@RequestMapping("/checklogin")
public @ResponseBody String newcallback( 
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException{

    String message = "<br><div style='text-align:center;'>"
                + "<h3>********** Hello World from plus sample servlet, Spring MVC Tutorial</h3>This message is coming from CrunchifyHelloWorld.java **********</div><br><br>";


    String APPLICATION_NAME = "PlusSample";
    java.io.File DATA_STORE_DIR =
          new java.io.File(System.getProperty("user.home"), ".store/plus_sample");
    FileDataStoreFactory dataStoreFactory = new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR);;

    // Set up the HTTP transport and JSON factory
    HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
    JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    // Load client secrets
    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(jsonFactory,
        new InputStreamReader(BaseController.class.getResourceAsStream("/client_secrets.json")));

    // set up authorization code flow
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
        httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets,
        Collections.singleton(CalendarScopes.CALENDAR)).setDataStoreFactory(dataStoreFactory)
        .build();

 // Authorize
    //http://localhost:8080/counterwebapp/oauth2callback
    //LocalServerReceiver receiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setHost("http://localhost:8080/counterwebapp/oauth2callback").setPort(8080).build();
    LocalServerReceiver receiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8080).build();
 Credential credential =
     new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow,receiver).authorize("user");

// Set up the main Google+ class
 Plus plus = new Plus.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential)
     .setApplicationName("Spring API Demo")
     .build();

 // Make a request to access your profile and display it to console
 Person profile = plus.people().get("me").execute();
 /*System.out.println("ID: " + profile.getId());
 System.out.println("Name: " + profile.getDisplayName());
 System.out.println("Image URL: " + profile.getImage().getUrl());
 System.out.println("Profile URL: " + profile.getUrl());*/

 logger.debug("ID : ",profile.getId());
 logger.debug("Name : ",profile.getDisplayName());
 logger.debug("[welcomeName] counter : {}", ++counter);

    return VIEW_INDEX;
            //----Credential credential =       authFlow.loadCredential(Utils.getUserId(req));

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem by using another set of APIs. I could not wrap my head around the new localserverreceiver() api.Moreover, being a naive web developer, I do not have the basic foundations correct which led me to the dilemma. Anyways for some one who is in similar situation as me will find the below code useful. I hope google could have documented the JAVA apis for OAuth2 in a similar way.

```
@RequestMapping("/simplelogin")
public @ResponseBody void simplemethod( 
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException{
String REDIRECT_URI = "http://localhost:8080/counterwebapp/redirect";
HttpTransport httpTransport=new NetHttpTransport();
  JsonFactory jsonFactory=new JacksonFactory();
  final Collection<String> SCOPE = Arrays.asList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile;https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email;https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar".split(";"));
  GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow=new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(httpTransport,jsonFactory,CLIENT_ID,CLIENT_SECRET,SCOPE).setAccessType("online").setApprovalPrompt("auto").build();
  //GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow=new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(httpTransport,jsonFactory,CLIENT_ID,CLIENT_SECRET,Collections.singleton(CalendarScopes.CALENDAR)).setAccessType("online").setApprovalPrompt("auto").build();
  String url=flow.newAuthorizationUrl().setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI).build();
  System.out.println("Please open the following URL in your browser then type the authorization code:");
  System.out.println("  " + url);   
  response.sendRedirect(
          flow.newAuthorizationUrl().setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI).build());
  return;
}



@RequestMapping("/redirect")
@ResponseBody String CallSampleServlet_sub( 
    HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException{
final String USER_INFO_URL = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo";
GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow authFlow = Utils.initializeFlowCalendar();
HttpTransport httpTransport=new NetHttpTransport();
  JsonFactory jsonFactory=new JacksonFactory();
String code= request.getParameter("code");
System.out.println("code "+ code);

final Collection<String> SCOPE = Arrays.asList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile;https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email;https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar".split(";"));
GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow=new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(httpTransport,jsonFactory,CLIENT_ID,CLIENT_SECRET,Collections.singleton(CalendarScopes.CALENDAR)).setAccessType("online").setApprovalPrompt("auto").build();
//GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(httpTransport,JSON_FACTORY, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, SCOPE).build();
  GoogleTokenResponse resp 
  =flow.newTokenRequest(code).setRedirectUri("http://localhost:8080/counterwebapp/redirect").execute();
  System.out.println((resp.getAccessToken()));
  //GoogleCredential credential=new GoogleCredential().setFromTokenResponse(resp);
  GoogleTokenResponse resp2 = new GoogleTokenResponse();
  resp2.setAccessToken(resp.getAccessToken());

  final Credential credential = flow.createAndStoreCredential((TokenResponse) resp2, null);
  System.out.println("credential created: "+ credential);
    com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar service = new com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar.Builder(
            httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential)
            .setApplicationName("Spring API Demo")
            .build();   

    System.out.println("<h1>HELLO WORLD Prafull</h1>");

    DateTime now = new DateTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
    System.out.println("<h2>" + service.getApplicationName() + "</h2>");
    CalendarList feed = service.calendarList().list().execute();
    Events even = service.events().list("primary").setMaxResults(10).setTimeMin(now).setOrderBy("startTime").setSingleEvents(true).execute();
    com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Events events = service.events().list("primary")
            .setMaxResults(10)
            .setTimeMin(now)
            .setOrderBy("startTime")
            .setSingleEvents(true)
            .execute();
    System.out.println("No upcoming events first found.");
    List<Event> items = events.getItems();
    if (items.size() == 0) {
        System.out.println("No upcoming events found.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Upcoming events");
        for (Event event : items) {
            DateTime start = event.getStart().getDateTime();
            if (start == null) {
                start = event.getStart().getDate();
            }
            System.out.printf("%s (%s)\n", event.getSummary(), start);
        }
    } 
  final HttpRequestFactory requestFactory = httpTransport.createRequestFactory(credential);
    // Make an authenticated request
    final GenericUrl url = new GenericUrl(USER_INFO_URL);
    final HttpRequest req = requestFactory.buildGetRequest(url);
    req.getHeaders().setContentType("application/json");
    final String jsonIdentity = req.execute().parseAsString();
    final String jsonIdentit1y = req.execute().parseAsString();

    Oauth2 oauth2 = new Oauth2.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), credential).setApplicationName(
              "Oauth2").build();
     Userinfoplus userinfo = oauth2.userinfo().get().execute();
     System.out.println(userinfo.toPrettyString());

     com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.gson.Gson usergson = new com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.gson.Gson();
     Userinfoplus user = usergson.fromJson(jsonIdentity, Userinfoplus.class);
     System.out.println(user.getFamilyName()+ "  "+ user.getGivenName()+ " "+ user.getEmail());
    System.out.println(jsonIdentity);
    return VIEW_INDEX;
}
```